# Enums that hold Conditional Logic - Possible?

Tags: java, enums, conditional-statements, predicate

To clarify, I want something like this:

```
MESSAGE_1042("messageText", p -> p.contains(MESSAGE_1032), p -> p.isAThing());
```

Where later, I can call as such:

```
for (Message message : Messages) {
    if (message.conditionsMet()) {
        //doTheThing
    }
}
```

I don't actually care if I can use lambdas, or Predicates, or how I set the conditions, or how they're tested. I know that I could do this with my own classes, where I just extend the class and implement conditionsMet() for each individual class.

However, I expect I will eventually have a LOT of these things, and I don't want to have a package containing hundreds of classes, when I could have a single Enum with many lines instead.

For more background information: this is for a personal project. A sort of interactive story I'm working on, and these messages are things the user can say. However, there can be multiple conditions that might determine if they have the option to actually say a message.

If I can store the conditions in the enum holding the text, then that's more convenient to me. When I'm working with the enum itself in my other code, I won't have to worry about its special conditions. It knows its own conditions before it's allowed to be used, and I want to just ask it if those conditions are met.

So is there any reasonable way to obtain this in an enum? Or am I going to have to just accept having lots of classes?

Comment: sure, you can pass lambda expression to enum constructor.

Comment: @bayou.io That becomes an issue when you want to have an unknown number of predicates, each with a different generic type. Sure, I can do Predicate<HashSet<String>> and p -> p.contains(string). And the second parameter can be Predicate<HashSet<Integer>>) p -> p == 2. But that would require me to pass in a p -> true predicate for each condition that doesn't matter, every time. You cannot overload Predicate<HashSet<String>> with any other predicate. It would be all or nothing, which while doable, doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: not sure about your use case. care to elaborate it a little more? give a few concrete examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override methods in individual enum items.

```
enum Message {
   A() {
      @Override
      public boolean conditionsMet() {
          ...
      }
   },
   B() {
      @Override
      public boolean conditionsMet() {
          ...
      }
   },
   ...
   ;
   public abstract boolean conditionsMet();
}
```

Then given an instance of `Message`, calling `conditionsMet()` will pick up the implementation from the particular instance.

You can mark enum methods as abstract as long as the instances themselves provide implementations.

(Thanks dkatzel.)

Comment: you could also make `conditionsMet()` abstract which would force all instances to implement it

Comment: I did not know you could do this! This looks like it might be my best shot so far.

Edit: almost forgot to say thanks!

Comment: if this works, it can also be redesigned to have a constructor accepting a predicate. in java8, subclassing an abstract class falls out of favor, to constructor accepting lambda.

Answer (score 0):

`enum`s in Java area special kind of class that you can't instansiate from the outside and can't extend, but it's still essentially a class. `enum`s can have members and methods, so you can have the entire logic contained in the `enum` itself. E.g.:

```
public enum Message {
    MESSAGE1(true), MESSAGE2(false);

    private boolean condition;

    private Message(boolean condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public boolean conditionMet() {
        return condition;
    }
}
```

Comment: The difficulty comes from needing the condition to be calculated at the time conditionMet() is called.